# How to create a legend and change the point shape in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I need to reproduce the following figure

[image: Figure I need to reproduce]

on R Studio for a macroeconomics project. I've been able to figure most of it out, but the stuff that's giving me the biggest issue is the legend and changing the shapes of the data points. Here is what I have so far

[image: How far I've gotten]

Here is my code with the data points input manually

```
# `First I load up some packages`

library(tidyverse)

# `then I create vectors for the years and percentages for Europe and the US`

year <- c(1900, 1910, 1920, 1930, 1940, 1950, 1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 200, 2010)
us_percent <- c(40.5, 40.9, 44.7, 45.1, 36.5, 33.7, 34.1, 33.4, 37.5, 42.4, 46.9, 48.8)
 euro_percent <- c(45.9, 45.8, 39.5, 40.5, 33.8, 31.7, 31.6, 29.7, 29.4, 32.4, 34, 34.7)

# `then I create a data frame for my vectors and name it`

df <- data.frame(year, us_percent, euro_percent)

# `then I create a ggplot function for the US and Europe inequality`

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=df, mapping=aes(x=year, y=euro_percent), color="cyan") +
  geom_point(data=df, mapping=aes(x=year, y=euro_percent), color="cyan", ) +
  geom_line(data=df, mapping=aes(x=year, y=us_percent), color="purple") +
  geom_point(data=df, mapping=aes(x=year, y=us_percent), color="purple") +
  xlim(1900, 2010) +
  ylim(25, 50) +
  labs(x="Year", y="Share of Total Pretax Income", title="Income Inequality")
```

I tried running various versions of `scale_color_manual` program, but it would leave it so my R console would show a "+" sign, and I don't know what to add after that. Any suggestions would be welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Pivot your data to long format and map the currency to shape and color aesthetics.

It's also a good idea to pick colors, sizes and themes that make your data and the differences between series clearly visible

```r
ggplot(tidyr::pivot_longer(df, -1, names_to = "Currency"), 
       aes(year, value, color = Currency)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(shape = Currency), size = 4) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("orange2", "deepskyblue3")) +
  theme_light() +
  xlim(1900, 2010) +
  ylim(25, 50) +
  labs(x="Year", 
       y="Share of Total Pretax Income", 
       title="Income Inequality",
       color = "", shape = "")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `shape =` argument. In general with `ggplot2` it's advisable to have a dataset in "long" format before plotting - much easier to then add a legend, if you add the stratification variables in the `aes()` as shapes and colours.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

legend_labels <- c("Top 10% Income share: Europe", "Top 10% Income share: US")
df |> pivot_longer(cols = ends_with("percent"),
                   names_to = "area",
                   values_to = "percent") |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = percent, colour = area)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = area)) +
  geom_line() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1900, 2010),
                  ylim = c(25, 50)) +
  labs(x = "",
       y = "Share of top income decile\nIn total pretax income\n(decennial averages)",
       title = "Income Inequality",
       colour = "",
       shape = "") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1900, 2020, 10)) +
  scale_colour_discrete(labels = legend_labels) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(2, 15), labels = legend_labels, ) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank())
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Thank you, I was able to use your information and some help from the other comments to reproduce most of the graph. However, I have just two more questions:


1.)  How did you get the lines to connect to the y axis? Mine still has a "gap" like the original and the other graphs submitted?

2.) Also, in the original plot they had each decade listed from 1900-2010, whereas my graph and yours show 30 year intervals. How would we fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: 1) I set the `panel.grid.` arguments in `theme()` to `element_blank()` - so removing the grid lines for the x axis and the minor grid lines for the y-axis. 2) You can manually pick the `breaks =` in a `scale_x_continuous()` layer - see updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually specifying the color (in your case, "cyan" and "purple") transform your data from 'wide' to 'long' and create a new variable that categorizes each observation into "US" or "EURO". This can be done with the `gather()` from dplyr (fixed your typos as well):

```
Year <- c(1900, 1910, 1920, 1930, 1940, 1950, 1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010)
us_percent <- c(40.5, 40.9, 44.7, 45.1, 36.5, 33.7, 34.1, 33.4, 37.5, 42.4, 46.9, 48.8)
euro_percent <- c(45.9, 45.8, 39.5, 40.5, 33.8, 31.7, 31.6, 29.7, 29.4, 32.4, 34, 34.7)

df <- data.frame(Year, us_percent, euro_percent)

df_long <- df %>% gather(key = "Country", value = "Percentage", us_percent:euro_percent, factor_key = TRUE)
# Where: key is the new indicator name, value is the stacked data column
```

Then, when you're data is set and ready, you can simply define the functional aesthetics (shape, color) within the main `ggplot()` function, like so:

```
ggplot(
  data = df_long,
  aes(
    x = Year,
    y = Percentage, 
    color = Country, 
    shape = Country
  )
) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() +
  xlim(1900, 2010) +
  ylim(25, 50) +
  labs(
    x="Year", 
    y="Share of Total Pretax Income", 
    title="Income Inequality"
  ) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_color_grey()
```

[image: Income Inequality]

Now you've got less code and a bit more room to wiggle with some additional aesthetic changes, if you want.